# How to use nmake for an C++ project

Tags: c++, windows, nmake

How do I set up a project using nmake like with GNU Make?

I got a certain folder structure I want to keep and would love if I could tell `cl` to put the obj files in a certain build folder.

I did not find any tutorial which actually describes a real project setup.
I am in desperate need of a short realistic example or a link to a tutorial actually dealing with my problem as [this](http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/08/nmake-makefile-tutorial-and-example.html) or [this](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/help/msc_nmake.php) are not even close to do any real explanation.

Comment: Did you found some valid answer about your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to try something new, I'd suggest using `cmake` to generate the NMake Makefiles for you. This has the additional advantage that you can generate Visual Studio project files, Unix Makefiles etc from the same build system generator.